# Storing app document folder file names in NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am storing some files in app documents folder. I want to store the names of those files in NSArray object. For example, I have 3 csv files in app called one, two, three. And I want to get these names in NSArray. I am using XCode 4.4.1 and iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:&error];
```

Comment: Here when i use error:&error an error apprears "Use of undeclared identifier 'error'"

Comment: updated my answer. I suggest you to read some basic material on iOS programming